# turn on bash -x

Tags: linux, bash

when I turned on the bash -x on my linux console for every command I type I get this output.

`printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"`

This is quite annoying, how can I turn it off.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question was not why, but how to fix. Type at your bash prompt:

```
unset PROMPT_COMMAND; PS1='\w> '
```

Now why. command in `PROMPT_COMMAND` are evaluated after every bash command (it sets `PS1`), you usually can not see this activity.   But with `-x` you can.

Answer (score 4):

This command output an escape sequence to change the title of the terminal emulator. So I guess it is configured in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` when `TERM` match `xterm*`. Have a look there and comment the code.

The command is printed because `bash -x` will display every command invoked, even if it is part of printing `$PS1`. That's why you probably don't want to use `set -x` in an interactive shell, but should probably put your code in a script and add `set -x` at the beginning and `set +x` at the end (optional unless you `source` it).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be your `$PROMPT_COMMAND` variable in action. You might want to just use `$PS1` instead.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-PPID

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set -x` to turn on debugging and `set +x` to turn it off.

When you have the debugging option on, BASH will print out the value of `$P4` for each line. By default, it is a simple `+` followed by a space. Try setting `PS4='+ '`.

If that doesn't work, you have a Kornshell user who used `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to set the prompt. It's common to display useful information such as user name, and directory in the prompt. In BASH, you can do that with various escape sequences. For example:

```
PS1="\u@\h:\w$ "
```

Will replace `\u` with the user name, `\h` with the short host name, and `\w` the current directory based upon the `$HOME` directory, if the user is in `$HOME/bin`, the prompt will display

```
david@foo-sys:~/bin$
```

If the user is in `/usr/bin`, the prompt will be

```
david!@foo-sys:/usr/bin$
```

With Kornshell, you can't use these *escape sequences*. Instead, you either alias the `cd` command, and have a cd function that sets the prompt. Or, you use the `$(..)` syntax. I use Kornshell, and my prompt looks like this:

```
PS1=$(print -n "`logname`@`hostname`:";if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] then; print -n "~${PWD#$HOME}"; else; print -n "$PWD";fi;print "\n$ ")
```

Nasty, isn't it? In BASH, I could have done this:

```
PS1="\u@\h:\w\n$ "
```

Anyway, it's common for Kornshell users to set `$COMMAND_PROMPT` variable instead of using the *escape sequences* when they use BASH because that's how they know to do it. And, when you do that, you'll see the prompt command printed out each and every time. For example, I could set my BASH prompt with this:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="print -n "`logname`@`hostname`:";if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] then; print -n "~${PWD#$HOME}"; else; print -n "$PWD";fi;print "\n$ "
```

and when I have `set -x` set, I'll see that print out each and every time.

What you should do is go into the `$HOME/.bash_profile` or if that doesn't exist `$HOME/.profile` file, and get rid of the line where `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set. Instead, change it to:

```
PS1="\e]0\u@\h:\w\a$ "
```

Which is more or less the same prompt. If you don't want to change your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, then simply do this:

```
$ unset PROMPT_COMMAND
$ PS="\e]0\u@\h:\w\a$ "
```

One more possibility: It could be that you don't see the prompt being set in `$HOME/.bash_profile`, `$HOME/.profile` or even `$HOME/.bashrc`. In that case, you have a System Administrator who's a Kornshell person, and they've set the prompt in the `/etc/profile` file. You'll have to override the prompt setting in your `$HOME/.bash_profile` file yourself by adding the two above lines at the end of the file.